# Perl and XPath: missing entries in database table

Tags: mysql, xml, perl, xpath, mariadb

I would like to extract data from an xml-file and import them into a MariaDB/MySQL database. The xml file is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database>
  <row1s>
    <row1 name="fox" category="mammal">
       <row2s>
         <row2 type="1" size="10"/>
         <row2 type="2" size="8"/>
       </row2s>
       </row1>
    <row1 name="horse" category="mammal">
       <row2s>
             <row2 type="3" size="100"/>
       </row2s>
    </row1>
    <row1 name="bee" category="insect"> 
       <row2s/>
    </row1>
    <row1 name="wasp" category="insect">
       <row2s/>
    </row1>
  </row1s>
</database>
```

and the Perl-code is:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new( filename => "animals4.xml" );
# my $xp = XML::XPath->new( ioref => \*DATA );

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:mysql:test", "user", "pw", { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0 } )
    or die "Fehler beim Verbidungsaufbau zum MariaDB-Server:" . " $DBI::err -< $DBI::errstr \n";

for my $row1 ( $xp->findnodes('//row1s/row1') ) {
    printf "Level --- row1 \"name\" gives: %s\n", $row1->getAttribute("name");

    for my $row2 ( $row1->findnodes('.//row2s/row2') ) {
        printf "Level row2 \"type\" gives: %s\n", $row2->getAttribute("type");
        printf "Level row2 \"size\" gives: %s\n", $row2->getAttribute("size");

        $dbh->do(
            "INSERT INTO animal4 (name, category,type,size) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",
            undef,
            $row1->getAttribute("name"),
            $row1->getAttribute("category"),
            $row2->getAttribute("type"),
            $row2->getAttribute("size")
        ) or die "Error during execution: " . "$DBI::err -> $DBI::errstr (animal $DBI::state)\n";
    }
}
```

The terminal output is:

```
Level --- row1 "name" gives: fox
Level row2 "type" gives: 1
Level row2 "size" gives: 10
Level row2 "type" gives: 2
Level row2 "size" gives: 8
Level --- row1 "name" gives: horse
Level row2 "type" gives: 3
Level row2 "size" gives: 100
Level --- row1 "name" gives: bee
Level --- row1 "name" gives: wasp
```

Which is what I expected. But the table has the following entries:

```
name  category  type    size
fox   mammal    1         10
fox   mammal    2          8
horse mammal    3        100
```

Bee and wasp are missed. Can anyone help me how to solve this problem? I wonder why this happend since the output of the terminal was ok.

Thanks for help.

Here is the code for the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test01.animal4 (
name VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL
, category VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL
, type     INTEGER DEFAULT NULL
, size     INTEGER DEFAULT NULL
);
```

This is a follow up question of [hierarchy problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626905/perl-and-xpath-considering-hierarchy).

Comment: You won't make many friends using the comma-first style in Perl! Use it with JavaScript if you must, but I wouldn't be convinced even then. It offers no benefit at all in Perl, because a trailing comma at the end of a list is legal, and just serves to startle and slow down experienced Perl coders.

Comment: @Borodin This is bad because I want to have many many Perl-friends and I will change my comma-style (even though I personaly find the first-comma much more convenient).

Comment: I intended that as an idiom. It will make little difference to the number of friends you make, but there are a lot of people who won't like to read your code. I have to look at it for several seconds before I think it is right. Comma-first in SQL statements makes more sense, but I have never seen it before anywhere but in JavaScript. In Perl you can put a comma after the last element of a list, and you can align all the trailing commas so that a missing one is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have an explanation and a fix, but I suggest the following changes

- You should `prepare` the `INSERT INTO` SQL statement and then `execute` it within the loop. `do` has a much bigger overhead
- The `//` ( `descendant-or-self::node()` ) XPath construct is expensive and you should reserve it for cases where you have no idea where the element will be within the document, which is very rare. In this case the `row1` elements are at `/database/row1s/row1` and the `row2` elements are at `row2s/row2` relative to that
- It is much cleaner to use different delimiters if you want to use quote characters within a quoted string. For instance `"My name is \"$name\""` is much better as `qq{My name is "$name"}`

Here's a version of your program that may help.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::XPath;
use DBI;

my $xp = XML::XPath->new( filename => 'animals4.xml' );

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
   'DBI:mysql:test', 'user', 'pw',
   { RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0}
) or die "Fehler beim Verbidungsaufbau zum MariaDB-Server: $DBI::err -< $DBI::errstr\n";

my $insert_animal = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO animal4 (name, category, type, size) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');

for my $row1 ( $xp->findnodes('/database/row1s/row1') ) {

   my $name     = $row1->getAttribute('name');
   my $category = $row1->getAttribute('category');

   printf qq{Level --- row1 "name" gives: $name\n};

   my @row2 = $xp->findnodes('row2s/row2', $row1);

   if ( @row2 ) {
      for my $row2 ( @row2 ) {

         my $type = $row2->getAttribute('type');
         my $size = $row2->getAttribute('size');

         print qq{Level row2 "type" gives: $type\n};
         print qq{Level row2 "size" gives: $size\n};

         $insert_animal->execute($name, $category, $type, $size);
      }
   }
   else {
      $insert_animal->execute($name, $category, undef, undef);
   }
}
```

**output**

```
Level --- row1 "name" gives: fox
Level row2 "type" gives: 1
Level row2 "size" gives: 10
Level row2 "type" gives: 2
Level row2 "size" gives: 8
Level --- row1 "name" gives: horse
Level row2 "type" gives: 3
Level row2 "size" gives: 100
Level --- row1 "name" gives: bee
Level --- row1 "name" gives: wasp
```

Comment: Thanks for this new design and explanation. I tried it but two strange things happened. First: the output on the terminal looks like the expected but the figure at horse/size is missing (100). Second: the entries in table of the database are ok for fox,bee and wasp, but the whole row for horse is missing (**horse/mammal/3/100**).

Comment: @giordano: I have run it against the XML data that you show in your question and the output is correct (I have added it to my solution). Please check that your XML is correct. Do you get `Level row2 "size" gives: ` in your output or is the entire row missing?

Comment: You're right. I accessed the wrong xml file where the line for horse has no size (`<row2 type="3"/>`). The code gives now the correct result. Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you very much for your help. The **real** original file has indeed a missing attribute size in the row2-element. This file comes from professional programmers (what I'm not as you can see) but I wonder why build **truncated** (removing attributes if they are empty). In my opinion a nice xml contains all attributes even they don't have a value (`<row2 type="3" size="" />`). But this is another issue.

Comment: @giordano: I disagree. An attribute should appear only if its value is different from any default it may have. It's common for an element to have attributes in the hundreds, and multi-line list of empty values helps no one. However I would expect something like `size` to be a required attribute as it can't have a default.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation. If I run the code with missing `size=""` in the xml-file the whole record (horse/mammal/3/NULL) won't be imported into the database. Can you help me how to cope with this?

Comment: @giordano: You continue to report highly unlikely symptoms. If there is a `rows2` element with no `size` attribute then `$row2->getAttribute('size')` will return a null string `''` which will be inserted into the database. You may want `NULL` instead of an empty string, but the record will certainly be written. Please look again. Are you running my solution program as it stands?

Comment: Yes. I copied it. The same result I'v got with the code of alien (below).

Comment: Something you're doing is inconsistent. I am certain that you have changed my code in a way that you are sure "won't make any difference". You should show the live code that you are running, or check by running this test program. I've rewritten my answer to replace all database operations with `print` statements instead [**here**](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4ea458d5f71ba7dbccc9). It uses the `DATA` file handle so it is self-contained. Please run it to check that you get the same results as I do.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I think there is a missunderstanding. The output on terminal was OK, the code gives the output which we expected using the old and this new one. The problem was that in the table of the datbase the row (horse/mammal/3/ /) is missing. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @giordano: Yes, I understand that; and as I said I have replaced the database `INSERT` operations with `print` statements that show the data that would be inserted. I *could* set up a MySQL server and make a database and a table that looked like yours, but I am confident that the output reflects what would happen if I did. You will have seen that it prints `-> Writing horse/mammal/3/` which is *correct* as the `size` field is a null string. If yours isn't doing that then it isn't a problem with the Perl code. If you haven't changed my code then the table definition isn't how you described it.

Comment: @giordano: There is little point in coming back to me to find out why it isn't working, as the problem doesn't lie in anything that you have described so far. Do you have any debugging skills at all? Surely you can establish whether the SQL `INSERT` is being called from the program? If so, but it isn't appearing in the database, then you must look at your table configuration. I am happy to help, but there is nothing I can do without new or different information from you, so please try to do something more than running programs and saying they don't work.

Comment: I will spend some time with this problem and inform you as soon I have more information.

Comment: Thanks to this [contribution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859285/how-do-i-insert-null-fields-with-perls-dbdpg) I could found a solution. After `my $size = $row2->getAttribute('size');`I added `if ( !$size ) { $size = undef};` . Obviously, $size was _empty_ but the record to be inserted needs the correct datatype for each value accordingly to the table specification or an "undef". Otherwise the whole record won't be inserted. Thanks for your patient.

Comment: @Borodin Do you have a style preference between `$xp->findnodes('row2s/row2', $row1)` versus `$row1->findnodes('row2s/row2')`?  I'm used to seeing the latter syntax with most other modules, so am just curious if there is any reason for a preference?

Comment: @Miller: I absolutely prefer the latter. My thinking was a little vague here but I was trying, perhaps misguidedly, to reflect my comment in the solution, *"the row2 elements are at `row2s/row2` relative to [each `row1`]"*

Answer (score 1):

From your code, the DB write only happens when your second query, for nodes under $row1, returns results:

```
for my $row1 ( $xp->findnodes('//row1s/row1') ){
    for my $row2 ( $row1->findnodes('.//row2s/row2') ) {
        $dbh->do("INSERT INTO animal4 (name, category,type,size) VALUES(?,?,?,?)"
        [...]  
        ) or die        ;   
    }
}
```

If there are no $row2 nodes, there is no database write.

If you want to have the database write occur regardless of the presence or absence of $row2 nodes, you need to move the db write out of that for loop, i.e.:

```
for my $row1 ( $xp->findnodes('//row1s/row1') ){
    # get name and category here
    my $name = $row1->getAttribute('name');
    my $cat = $row1->getAttribute('category');
    my $row2set = $row1->find('row2s/row2'); ## creates a Nodeset object
    if ($row2set->size > 0) {
        ## we found nodes!!
        foreach my $row2 ($row2set->get_nodelist) {
           # get size and type here
           my $type = $row2->getAttribute('type');
           my $size = $row2->getAttribute('size');
           # write to db

        }
    } else {
        ## no row2 nodes found.
        ## write to db - just write the row1 values; type and size will be undefined.

    }
}
```

NodeSet documentation: http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/XML-XPath-1.13/XPath/NodeSet.pm

**A quick note about setting variables and scope**

*Scope* refers to where an entity (a variable, a subroutine, an object, etc.) is visible and accessible in Perl code; setting the scope of entities helps to *encapsulate* them and prevent data or functions from being available everywhere to every part of the program.

Scope is set using code structures such as subroutines, loops, packages, objects--any block of code that is delimited by curly braces ( `{` and `}` ). It is standard practice in Perl (and many other languages) to increase indentation when entering a block and decrease it when leaving the block; that way, you can determine scope fairly easily when reading the code.

Using `my` sets the scope of a variable (or function, object, etc.) as limited to the block of code where the variable was set; e.g.

```
for my $row1 ( $xp->findnodes('//row1s/row1') ){
    # $row1 is available inside this code block

    my $row2set = $row1->find('row2s/row2');
    # $row2set is now available inside this code block

    if ($row2set->size > 0) {
        my $size = $row2set->size;
        # $size is now available inside this code block

        foreach my $row2 ($row2set->get_nodelist) {
            # $row2 is available inside this code block
            # we can also access $row1, $row2set, $size
        }

        # we can access $row1, $row2set, $size
        # $row2 is out of scope, i.e. we cannot access it

        say "The value of row2 is $row2";
        # Perl will complain 'Global symbol "$row2" requires explicit package name'
    }
    # we can access $row1 and $row2set
    # $size and $row2 are out of scope
}
# $row1, $row2set, $size, and $row2 are out of scope
```

Going back to your code, let's say you decide to set up variables `$name`, `$category`, `$type`, and `$size` to capture your data and write it to the database. You have to ensure that you set the scope of the variables correctly or they will store inappropriate data. For example:

```
# declare all our variables
my ($name, $cat, $type, $size);
for my $row1 ( $xp->findnodes('//row1s/row1') ){
    # we can set $name and $cat from the data in row1:
    $name = $row1->getAttribute('name');
    $cat = $row1->getAttribute('category');
    my $row2set = $row1->find('row2s/row2');
    if ($row2set->size > 0) {
        foreach my $row2 ($row2set->get_nodelist) {
            # row2 gives us the type and size info
            $type = $row2->getAttribute('type');
            $size = $row2->getAttribute('size');
            # "say" prints a string and adds a "\n" to the end,
            # so it's very handy for debugging
            say "row2s found: name: $name; category: $cat; type: $type; size: $size";
        }
    } else {
        say "row2s empty: name: $name; category: $cat; type: $type; size: $size";
    }
}
```

This gives us the following output:

```
row2s found: name: fox; category: mammal; type: 1; size: 10
row2s found: name: fox; category: mammal; type: 2; size: 8
row2s found: name: horse; category: mammal; type: 3; size: 100
row2s empty: name: bee; category: insect; type: 3; size: 100
row2s empty: name: wasp; category: insect; type: 3; size: 100
```

That is because the scope of `$type` and `$size` is set to the entire code block, and the values are preserved between each iteration of the row1 loop and the inner row2 loop. Bee and wasp don't have values for size and type, so the value from the previous animal is used instead.

There are lots of different ways to fix this problem, but the most efficient might be this:

```
my $db_insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO animal4 (name, category, type, size) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');

for my $row1 ( $xp->findnodes('//row1s/row1') ){
    my $row2set = $row1->find('row2s/row2');
    if ($row2set->size > 0) {
        foreach my $row2 ($row2set->get_nodelist) {
            # for debugging
            say "row2s found: name: " . $row1->getAttribute('name') .
            "; category: " . $row1->getAttribute('category') .
            "; type: " . $row2->getAttribute('type') .
            "; size: " . $row2->getAttribute('size');

            $db_insert->execute( $row1->getAttribute('name'),
            $row1->getAttribute('category'),
            $row2->getAttribute('type'),
            $row2->getAttribute('size') );
        }
    } else {
        # for debugging
        say "row2s empty: name: " . $row1->getAttribute('name') .
        "; category: " . $row1->getAttribute('category') .
        "; type: NOT SET" .
        "; size: NOT SET";
        $db_insert->execute( $row1->getAttribute('name'),
        $row1->getAttribute('category'),
        undef,
        undef );
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to add a Nodeset: `my @row2s = $xp->find('.//row2s/row2'); if (@row2s) { for my $row2 (@row2s) { ... } } else { ... }`

Comment: @alien Thanks for this code and explanation. It's strange. When I use your code each animal get the type and size from all animals: fox (1/10,2/8,3/100); horse(1/10,2/8,3/100), bee(1/10,2/8,3/100), wasp((1/10,2/8,3/100)).

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for this abbreviation. I tried it but I got the message (after: Level1 --- row1 "name" gives: fox): "Can't locate object methid "getAttribute" via paclage "XML::XPath::NodeSet" at proc.pl line 31". Line 31 is: `printf "Level row2 \"type\" gives: %s\n", $row2->getAttribute("type") `;

Comment: @giordano it sounds like you are setting the variables in the wrong place - try reading about variable scope in the perl docs. I can expand my code to fix the problem but I am just about to go to bed, so it will have to be tomorrow!

Comment: @OP: part of the problem is that the `$dbh->do` in your posted code is indented wrongly, making it hard to tell that it's inside the row2 loop.

Comment: @giordano, oops, typo, should be `findnodes` rather than `find` in the code in my comment.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the correction. Now I get the same what I wrote to alien above (each animal has all types and sizes).

Comment: @giordano I've added information on variable scope to my answer so I hope you'll be able to see why it is you got the incorrect results, and how to avoid it.

Comment: @giordano, As I said, it just a simpler way of writing the same thing.

Comment: ikemai and alien The reason for my faulty output (each animal with all type/size) was not a problem of scope but a wrong path in find resp. findnodes. Now, all version ($dbh->do() or $dbh->prepare(),if ($row2set->size > 0) or  if ( @row2 ) ) run and give the expected results. Thanks to all who contributed and spent so much time. I really appreciated it and now I have a good base to understand XML::XPath and XPath documents.